# Unauthorized error while trying to generate access token due to insufficient role to user account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Platform account (Gmail account) using which I am doing following in my Android Application:

1. Google Sign In
2. Generate Oauth 2.0 token
3. Generate Access token
4. Create item in Google Cloud Bucket
5. Adding elements to Google Cloud Bucket
6. Start machine learning model training job in GC
7. Access to googleapis

The member account I am using has default role as 'Owner'. Since it has the 'Owner' role, it can perform any action or modification in my Google Cloud.

Now I want to add another user Gmail account to my Google Cloud for users but to this Gmail account I want to give permissions limited only to above written tasks.

Initially, I gave the following roles to the user account:

1. Service Account Token Creator
2. ML Engine Developer
3. Storage Object Creator
4. Storage Object Viewer

However, I'm getting "Unauthorized error **401**" while trying to generate the access token. Which role should I add to solve this issue? Also, is there any other roles that I need to add so that I won't run into any other error codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I granted **ML Engine Developer** role to the user Gmail account and now somehow user account is able to perform all the operations without exploiting my cloud resources.

Comment: Perhaps you were first receiving this 401 error message because the access token needed to be refreshed, which then worked when this was done. Other potential reasons for receiving this error message can be found here: 

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#401_Unauthorized